# How to close active window with custom keyboard shortcut, only for selected applications

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I would like to set up several applications like document viewers and image viewers in Unity to close with one key pressed, preferably when <kbd>q</kbd> key is pressed. Most of the applications I use do not have a custom keyboard settings that flexible.

Is there a way to make <kbd>q</kbd> quit only selected applications and only if they are in active window? It can not quit any/all applications, because in some I actually want <kbd>q</kbd> to work as a letter.

Comment: I don't know why it has to be q... You could just use ALT+F4, that closes the active focused window by default.

Comment: @ByteCommander I am using Alt+F4 now, it is not what I am after, on my mini keyboard it is not very comfortable too.

Comment: And what about e.g CAPS-LOCK or a combination that is more comfortable? That way you don't have to restrict it to some applications only and can still type Qs.

Comment: The main challenge is to have the `q` key function selectively --- only when windows of certain applications are in focus. It'll be interesting to see what solutions people come up with.

Comment: I feel you'll need a script running all the time which will need to check whether `q` should function as a letter or as a signal to close a window.

Comment: @DKBose I feel that now too, I lived in hope there is an app for that.